# Decomposing squared integer input to sum of squared integers less than input?

Tags: php, arrays, algorithm

I have a question as follows:

> Given a positive integral number n, return a strictly increasing sequence (list/array/string depending on the language) of numbers, so that the sum of the squares is equal to n².
>
> decompose(11) must return [1,2,4,10]. Note that there are actually two ways to decompose 11², 11² = 121 = 1 + 4 + 16 + 100 = 1² + 2² + 4² + 10² but don't return [2,6,9], since 9 is smaller than 10 (if multiple sequence of squared integers can be used, go with the greatest one - so 10 instead of 9 in the above case).
>
> For decompose(50) don't return [1, 1, 4, 9, 49] but [1, 3, 5, 8, 49]
> since [1, 1, 4, 9, 49] doesn't form a strictly increasing sequence.

I have gotten nowhere, trying this (which probably is poorly done):

```php
function sq2squares($n) {

     $starting = ($n - 1) ** 2;
     $square = $n**2;
     $range = range(1, $n -1);
     $start = $square - $starting;

     foreach($range as $r => $v) {
          if($v**2 > $start) {
               unset($range[$r]);
          }
     }

    # $range here is [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];
    
    foreach(array_reverse($range) as $r) {
        if($r**2 < $start) {
            $start -= $r**2;
        }
    }

    print_r($results); // [49] || Should be: [1,3,5,8,49] 

}
```

I have subtracted square of input from largest next number (49) which leaves 99. Then I want to iterate over the remaining integers in `$range` (9-1) and subtract each but ONLY if the resulting subtraction results in `$start` being 0. That last part is what I can't figure out.

How to iterate over the array `$range` and only `array_push()` values which result in `$start` being 0? Thanks.

Comment: `since 9 is smaller than 10` this doesn't make sense.

Comment: It means if there are multiple integers whose squared sums equal the input, choose the ones which are the greatest. Does that make sense? Thanks.

Comment: I'm not overly concerned about that part though, what I don't quite get is how to subtract the remaining integers from `$range` such that the final subtraction sets `$start` to 0? And then push those elements into the array with 49 in it.

Comment: Can you edit the question and add this as it isn't there currently.

Comment: Yes, sure. Thanks for letting me know.

Comment: This is very similar to [subset sum problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem)

Comment: Is it ok with some other approach? Because current approach wants to exactly move on right numbers of the final solution which is very difficult to decide.

Comment: @nice_dev: Yes I am open to any other approach. I'm just trying to learn. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- We first create an array say `$dp` and fill all values with `-1`.
- Value `-1` means that there is no way to form sum of squared numbers for that particular number in iteration.
- Initialize `$dp[1] = 1` as base case.
- We iterate from `2` to `$value` where $value is the squared form.(121 for value 11).
- For every `$i` in the below code, we move from square root of `$i` till `1` looking for square sum solutions.
- If `$dp[$i - $j * $j] != -1` exists, it means that a previous problem, i.e, `$i - $j * $j` was solved, meaning, we could express it as sum of squared numbers and `$dp[$i - $j * $j] < $j` represents a check that we are looking for an strictly increasing sequence with bigger number with respect to previous subproblems. If both are true, assign `$dp[$i] = $j`.
- At the last, we need to collect values. We simply jump to previous subproblems and add value at current subproblem to result.

**Snippet:**

```
<?php

function decompose($value){
    $value *= $value;
    $dp = array_fill(0,$value + 1,-1);
    $dp[1] = 1;
    for($i = 2; $i <= $value; ++$i){
        for($j = intval( sqrt($i) ); $j >= 1; --$j){
            if($dp[$i - $j * $j] != -1 && $dp[$i - $j * $j] < $j){ // meaning can be represented as sum of squares
                $dp[$i] = $j;
                break; // since we are looking for sequence with greater numbers
            }
        }
    }
    
    $result = [];
    $curr = $value;
    // just collect all values
    while($dp[$curr] != -1){
        $result[] = $dp[$curr];
        $curr -= $dp[$curr] * $dp[$curr];
    }
    
    return $result;
}
```

**Demo:** https://3v4l.org/DEH9f